# ¿Como consultar por fecha a una tabla excluyendo la hora?

Tags: asp.net

Hola estoy tratando de trabajar en un pequeño filtro por fecha en net core , el problema que tengo es que en la tabla guardo hora y fecha y el input solo pasa fecha entonces al hacer la consulta no devuelve nada porque esta esperando fecha y hora, necesito trabajar el filtro para ir viendo por dias, ¿como puedo solucionarlo?

Esto es lo que llega por input

```
14-07-2020
```

Este es el formato que estoy guardando de Fecha:

```
15-07-2020 10:35:58
```

esta es la consulta que hago:

```
 return View(await _context.Venta.Where(x => x.Fecha == filtro).ToListAsync());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma podría ser comparar con dia, mes y año. Algo así:

```
return View(await _context.Venta.Where(x => x.Fecha.Day == day && x.Fecha.Month == month && x.Fecha.Year == year ).ToListAsync());
```